# How can I join multiple wav/flac/audio cds into one master big audio file (>4gb)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, flac, wav

I have multiple Audio CDs that I want to merge into one final flac or mp3 file. For example I have 10 audio cds. I can encode each CD into its single wave/flac file, or even mp3, but then I need to join them. I cannot create one single wav file because of its limitation to 4GB. How can I create only one master big audio file ?

I must be able to do the job with a command line tool (or multiple).
I tried `shntool`, but it doesn't work. Maybe I could do this with ffmpeg but I didn't find yet the correct command line (OSX or linux).

Comment: try [R64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RF64) a BWF format [or even W64 but I've never used that myself]. idk what tools you'd need to do that outside a pro DAW, but that's what to search for.

Comment: Looks like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/features) can do it, using the optional [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for anyone who will need the solution. I use "SoX" program (http://sox.sourceforge.net/). It join/merge/append multiple audio file super easily, without transcoding them in WAV as other programs do (which put a limitation on the file size).

Comment: Thanks so much - this utility is brilliant! This syntax worked for me: `sox *.flac output.flac`. All the files were combined into `output.flac`.